# performance of IfxBulkCopy?

Tags: .net, informix

I just want to check if I'm doing things correctly. This is the code with which I've tested the class:

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        using (IfxConnection conn = new IfxConnection("Server=infdb.du.laus.hr:9089;UserID=*;Password=*;Database=argosy4sdr;Persist Security Info=True;"))
        {
            conn.Open();

            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            data.Columns.Add("numb");

            data.Rows.Add(5);
            data.Rows.Add(8);
            data.Rows.Add(9);

            IfxBulkCopy bulk = new IfxBulkCopy(conn);
            bulk.DestinationTableName = "bulktest";
            bulk.WriteToServer(data);
        }
        sw.Stop();

        MessageBox.Show(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
```

Everything works as expected but the average run time is 780ms or nearly a second? By constrast three executions of IfxCommand object runs in 4ms.

Why is there such a difference? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: did you try strip where occur this delay? what java command... is at writetosrver()? rows.add?

Comment: I apologize for forgetting to mention that this is .NET and c#.